# Merge objects in softbody simulation

Tags: mesh, physics, soft-body

I have joined the objects but they just won't hold together. In the first image, it's as it should be and on the second once it hits the ground, the objects get separated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show some of your settings please?  How did you join the objects?

Comment: Selected the objects (The head, foots, torso etc) and then ctrl + j

Comment: Here is the link: https://blend-exchange.com/b/5aV0NSMZ/   This is without doing what you said, didn't really understand...

Comment: It only selected just a part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have joined cubes into one object, but in Edit mode vertices are not merged.

Hower with a cursor above a vertex and hit <kbd>L</kbd> (Select Linked) ...

- your mesh is selected partly - means vertices are not connected. This is the reason why it falls as separated.

[image]

- it should behave like this ... I used *Remesh modifier > Blocks* to quickly generate merged cubes at similar density like yours ...

[image]

---

BTW - Your topology is too uneven and dense.
Wire density has essential impact on simulation result.

[image]

With the same Softbody setup, but low poly resolution ...

[image]

Here after *Limited Disolve* <kbd>X</kbd> operator ...

[image]

---

Note: You have to *Apply* *Remesh* modifier before simulation, because *Softbody* sim is calculated first and *Remesh* after - so it wouldn't be taken into a count in simulation.

Comment: But how do I connect them like that? In the easiest way?

Comment: Like I wrote - Remesh modifier

Comment: Sorry missed that. Could you send the file after the remesh modifier? Since mine still is messed up after adding blocks. It looks very weird and in edit mode, it still doesn't behave like yours...

Comment: Here is the blend https://blend-exchange.com/b/lMrKnrAq/ but as you can see in examples none of this version gives you desired result. I just wanted to answer your Q - Why it fails separated and show how topo matters. How to get proper sim with such object with details like tail or eyes, would be better ask a new one if needed.

Comment: How do I get back the material? Thanks for all the help btw!

Comment: By remeshing you lost UVmaps. You would have to unwrap from scratch. But before I would suggest to solve topology of your mesh. Remeshing was a dirty way to get quickly compact mesh based on your very messy and imprecise work. Minecraft is great for its precise cubic grid that you totally destroyed, sorry. BTW another way can be create a "dummy" (proxy mesh) with simple topology used for soft-body sim and "Mesh Deform" modifier for your original mesh using dummy object as deformer.

Comment: Did you download texture and build your mesh? Or there was a mesh delivered with texture?

Comment: there was a mesh delivered with texture, from mcprep.

Comment: I'm going for something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSBz7EAs0bU Another question how do I make it high poly again?

Comment: Comments are not allowed to use for chatting. Please create a new question (with description what you tried and didnt work for you) Try to search similar question if already asked. Thank you